# Haskell "stack" won't load ghc-mod

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I think I might have created confusion.  Here are bash command line entries I used to install Stack to start with:

```
curl -sSL https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh  
echo 'export PATH=\$HOME/.local/bin:\$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc  
stack setup
```

So far this works, and I can test the compiler and the interactive environment and they work fine (ghc and ghci).

Then, when I try to install ghc-mod, it fails:

```
stack install ghc-mod
```

This command fails saying that ghc-boot-8.4.4 is not in my indices.  I get the same error if I remove everything, start over, and install the bundled version (Haskell.org).

Again, any help much appreciated.

=== Previous post ===
All:
A few more details.  I have tried the suggestions, and I've also tried removing the ~/.stack/indices directory and then running "stack update" to refresh it.

The same error still happens when trying to do "stack install ghc-mod" or "stack build ghc-mod", i.e. "The following package identifiers were not found in your indices: ghc-boot-8.4.4."

Any help much appreciated.

Best regards, David

=== Original Question ===
Problem: stack install ghc-mod fails, missing ghc-boot-8.4.4

My question is:  how do I get my environment to load the required modules (ghc-boot) into the index?

Hello All:
My apologies in advance for being an absolute newbie to Haskell.  Better late than never.  Here’s the background.

My goal is to get “Atom with Haskell” working on My MacOS version 10.13.6.

There are a couple of thoughtful pages that attempt to lead one through getting things to work:
    http://www.jkrause.io/blog/2016/03/26/setup-atom-io-for-developing-haskell-on-osx/
    https://github.com/simonmichael/haskell-atom-setup

I have attempted to follow these instructions loading the GHC environment, and I’ve also tried loading the complete platform:
    https://www.haskell.org/platform/mac.html

GHC and GHCi appear to work just fine in all three cases.

The problem comes with the following step, and happens the same way following either of the two sets of instructions:

$ stack install ghc-mod

```
Didn't see ghc-boot-8.4.4 in your package indices
Updating and trying again.
Selected mirror https://s3.amazonaws.com/hackage.fpcomplete.com/          
Downloading timestamp                                                  
No updates to your package index were found                           
Update complete                                                        
The following package identifiers were not found in your indices: ghc-boot-8.4.4
Possible candidates: ghc-boot-8.4.3, ghc-boot-8.4.1, ghc-boot-8.4.2.
```

I’ve tried many things, but have been unable to move past this error, i.e. that ghc-boot-8.4.4 is not found in my index.  I’m using lts-12.17.  Examining the page for its-12.17, it appears that ghc-boot-8.4.4 should be in the index, see https://www.stackage.org/lts-12.17.

Thanks, David

Comment: Are you using someone's branch of `ghc-mod`? It seems the project proper does not yet support `ghc-8.4`.
https://github.com/DanielG/ghc-mod/issues/931

Comment: Hi Dan:  I've actually tried to stay as "vanilla" as possible, and downloaded 8.4.3 from here (for Mac) https://www.haskell.org/platform/mac.html.  I tried some other kinds of download (home-brew) but removed all that.  I've always been mystified that the version is 8.4.3, yet it consistently seems to point at ghc-boot-8.4.4.  I am not using branches, nor am I downloading from git.

Comment: you also mentioned "I’m using lts-12.17" which specifies `ghc-8.4.4`. Stack can install ghc-8.4.4 for you, and usually does by default, unless you have specified something in your stack.yaml that tells it not to.

Answer (score 1):

ghc-boot-8.4.4 is not present on hackage, for some reason. (As of Nov 11, 2018)

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-boot

I'm not sure why stack would need to find it in the hackage index, though. It comes already installed with ghc.

Answer (score 0):

`ghc-boot` for 8.4.4 exists - `https://www.stackage.org/lts-12.17/package/ghc-boot-8.4.4`

If you run `stack update` and then try again, that may solve it.

If not, then I would switch back to resolver `lts-12-14` and use GHC 8.4.3 instead.

Comment: I did run "stack update" again (no luck there).  I then changed the line in my configuration file ~/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml to "resolver: its-12.14", removed ~/.stack/indices/Hackage directory, and reran "stack update."  I still get the "... not found in your indices:  ghc-boot-8.4.4.

Comment: Hi Tylerweir:  I have a question about your answer.  You suggested GHC 8.4.3.  That's what I installed from Haskell.org.  The references are all what came down in the bundle.  Also, how do I change to lts-12-14?  Is that defined in the ~/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml file?  Here's the link to what I installed (GHC 8.4.3).  https://www.haskell.org/platform/mac.html  Thanks for the help

Comment: @DEzell I would not install GHC that way, I would instead install stack and let it install GHC per project.

Comment: Thanks @tylerwier, that was my original attempt to install.  The instructions recommended exactly what you're recommending:  https://github.com/simonmichael/haskell-atom-setup. I got exactly the same result when I got to the step to install ghc-mod.